# How to pass future functions to a void function

Tags: flutter, dart

I wonder if it is possible if I want to pass functions to a void function?

As in the below example I have a void function as `firstFunction()`, then I want to pass functions like `print('do something');` and `print('do final Function');` in it.

This is the code example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            firstFunction(
              myFunctions: () async {
                // this is functions that I want to execute after the first function
                await print('do something');
                await print('do final Function');
              },
            );
          },
          child: const Text("Press"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void firstFunction({void myFunctions}) {
    print('do first function');
    myFunctions; // this is functions that I want to execute after the first function
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you `await`ing the calls to `print`?  It is not asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed possible. Your code seems correct, except your function declaration. I think it should be something like this:

```dart
void firstFunction({required Function myFunctions}) async {
  print('do first function');
  await myFunctions(); // this is functions that I want to execute after the first function
}
```

(Dind't test the code, let me know if there are still errors)

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the type of `myFunctions` of type `Function` instead of `void`.

Example:

```
  void firstFunction({required Function myFunctions}) async {
    print('do first function');
    await myFunctions(); // call the function that was passed as an argument
  }
```